# http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#/ 406 - Not Acceptable

Tags: swagger-ui

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html#/ deosn;t display Ui page."406 - Not Acceptable" is the error.but http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs and /swagger-resources work fine with no error.

there is no duplicate in the dependencies.

what should be the issue?

Comment: Which version of Swagger UI are you using?

Comment: Which library/framework are you using (Springfox, Swashbuckle, etc.)? Also please post your Swagger UI configuration code so that others can reproduce the issue you are seeing.

Comment: Is your issue the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642179/configuring-swagger-ui-with-spring-boot) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40789139/113116)?

Comment: springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui version 2.7.0

Comment: yes @Helen, its the first issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Swagger UI with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43642179/configuring-swagger-ui-with-spring-boot)

Comment: @Bean
     public Docket api() {
         return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .select()
   .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(""))
                 .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                 .build().securitySchemes(apiKey());
     }

Comment: No, there is no duplicate. Can it be related to CORS config or spring security?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger UI causing HTTP 406 Not Acceptable response for operations producing content types other than json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926619/swagger-ui-causing-http-406-not-acceptable-response-for-operations-producing-con)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in ConfigureServices of Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters().AddApiExplorer();
```